# how to create link with a list of turtles in Netlogo

Tags: netlogo

I want to create link from turtle 0 with special list of turtles for example [2 7 6 5] . this list contains who of turtles

```
ask turtle 0 [
create-link-with [2 7 6 5]

let result requester-list 
ask turtle 0 [
create-links-to result
```

Answer (score 2):

As a general rule of thumb, don't use `who` in NetLogo. You don't provide the code that generated that list of `who` numbers, but it is almost always better to have a list of the turtles, not a list of the identifiers of the turtles.

Here is one way to do it (untested). There are better ways but I think this is more readable:

```
foreach [2 7 6 5]
[ this-turtle ->
  ask turtle 0 [create-link-with turtle this-turtle ]
]
```

If you instead were using an agentset, your code would look more like this:

```
let targets n-of 4 turtles
ask turtle 0 [create-links-with targets]
```